# Como usar a formatação do sympy e do LaTeX sem usar o jupyter notebook?

Tags: python

atualmente tenho estudado as bibliotecas sympy e LaTeX, porém só vi pessoas conseguindo usar a formatação das bibiliotecas na forma de jupyter notebook. Há alguma maneira de utilizar essas bibliotecas com as suas respectivas formatações sem usar o notebook e usando o vscode?

Comment: Não sei em relação ao sympy, mas o látex é possivel, basta usar um editor latex e instale as dependências. no Linux seria o Tex live

Comment: Existem vária diversas maneiras de criar representação para notação matemática com python. Sem saber qual a interface será usada para renderizar essa notação fica difícil dar uma orientação. Considere [edit] a pergunta e fornecer mais informação a respeito do problema.

Comment: Não duplique perguntas, comentários e edições devem ser feitas na [pergunta original](/q/586859/3635).